# Validate Presence of XML Element in a XML file

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have a XML File as shown below ,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<MainClass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Items>
    <Settings xsi:type="FileModel">
      <Name>FileOne</Name>
      <IsActive>true</IsActive>
      <IsHidden>false</IsHidden>
    </Settings>
    <Settings xsi:type="FileModel">
      <Name>FileTwo</Name>
      <IsActive>true</IsActive>
      <IsHidden>false</IsHidden>
    </Settings> 
   <Settings xsi:type="ServerModel">
      <Name>DelRep</Name>
      <IsActive>false</IsActive>
      <IsHidden>false</IsHidden>
    </Settings>
  </Items>
  <DirectoryPath>D:\MainFolder</DirectoryPath>
</MainClass>
```

I am extracting some data using the Following code ,

```
XDocument File = XDocument.Load(path);
XElement element = File .Root.Elements().Single(x => x.Name == "DirectoryPath");
string usingPath = element.Value;
```

I have been trying to add a certain validation to the above code such that even in a situation that the xml file is missing the part `<DirectoryPath>D:\MainFolder</DirectoryPath>` , I would not get the error " **sequence contains no matching element** ".

Is there a property Similar to may be Path.Exist in C# to validate the presence of an XML element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [SingleOrDefault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.singleordefault?view=netframework-4.8), which returns default value if the element is not found

```
XElement element = File .Root.Elements().SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == "DirectoryPath");
if(element != null)
{
    string usingPath = element.Value;
}
```

Comment: As described in the code, you could use a null check before assigning the value.

Answer (score 0):

Use: SignleOrDefault. Then you will get proper XElement or null.

Answer (score 0):

There is no default method to verify whether the given node exists or not.But we can use **extension methods** to achieve the same.

```
public static class XElementExtension
{
    public static bool HasElement(this XElement xElement, string elementName)
    {
        return xElement.Elements(elementName).Any();
    }        
}

// Main
var xmlDocument = XElement.Load(@"TestFile.xml", LoadOptions.None); 
string elementName = "DirectoryPath";
bool hasElement = xmlDocument.HasElement(elementName);
if(hasElement)
{
    Console.WriteLine(xmlDocument.Elements(elementName).First().Value);
}
```